# Python and protocol buffer: how to removed an element from a repeated message field

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

Accordingly to protocol buffer [python generated code documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated), 
I can add a object to a repeated message field this way:

```
foo = Foo()
bar = foo.bars.add()        # Adds a Bar then modify
bar.i = 15
foo.bars.add().i = 32       # Adds and modify at the same time
```

but:

1. how can I remove `bar` from `bars`?
2. how can I remove the `n-th` bar element from `bars`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It took me more than a few minutes to get the proto buffer compiler installed correctly, so that may be reason enough to ignore this :)

Although it isn't in the documentation, you can actually treat a repeated field much like a normal list. Aside from its private methods, it supports `add`, `extend`, `remove` and `sort`, and `remove` is what you are looking for in the first case:

```
foo.bars.remove(bar)
```

Here is the output when printing `foo` before the above line (as defined by your code above) and after:

> ```
> Original foo:
> bars {
>   i: 15
> }
> bars {
>   i: 32
> }
>
> foo without bar:
> bars {
>   i: 32
> }
> ```

As for removing the `nth` element, you can use `del` and the index position you want to delete:

```py
# Delete the second element
del foo.bars[1]
```

And the output:

> ```py
> Original foo:
> bars {
>   i: 15
> }
> bars {
>   i: 32
> }
>
> Removing index position 1:
> bars {
>   i: 15
> }
> ```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a version issue, but the ".remove" method of deletion does not work for me. The second version does work.